# Backbone nested views - child view attributes incorrectly set in the template

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, mv

I'm trying to create a Backbone Model (lets call it `Library`) which contains a Collection of other Models (lets call them `Books`). I am providing a view - `LibraryView`, which creates an HTML of a book case with a set of books represented by HTML generated by `BookView`. Also, I am using Handlebars.js as my templating system.

The issue I am experiencing is that my `BookView` returns weird html on this.el element, before I even pass it through `render()` function.

**LibraryModel Model**

```
  var LibraryModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function() {

      var books = new BookCollection();

      _.each(book_data.books, function(value, index) {
        books.add(new Book());
      });

      this.books = books;

    }
  });
```

**LibraryView View:**

```
 var LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: "#library",

    render: function() {

      var t = this;

      this.model.books.each(function(book, index) {
        //create new view for each Book model in the books collection
        var view = new BookView(book);
        //append HTML produced by the BookView into LibraryView el element
        t.$el.append(view.render().$el);
      });

      return this;  
    },

    initialize: function() {
      //snip
    }
  });
```

**BookView View:**

```
  var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({

    render: function() {
      var viewmodel = this.model;
      var source = $("#book-template").html();
      var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
      var html = template(viewmodel.toJSON());

      console.log(html); //prints <div test="wtf" anotherTest="123"><b>wtf</b> 123</div>
      this.$el.html(html);

      return this;  
    },

    initialize: function(book) {
      console.log(this.el.outerHTML); //prints <div test="wtf" anotherTest="123"></div>
      this.model = book;
      this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
    }
  });
```

Template I am providing is: `<b>{{test}}</b> {{anotherTest}}`

**BookModel Model**

```
  var BookModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      test: "wtf",
      anotherTest: 123
    },

    initialize: function() {
        //snip
    }
  });
```

Basically, the issue I am exeperiencing is that my `BookView` produces weird HTML where each of my model attributes is attached to the Backbone-generated `div`, like this:

```
<div test="wtf" anotherTest="123">
<b>wtf</b> 123
</div>
```

I am not setting any of the attributes anywhere else in the code - both values are only coming from the defaults.

Also, I confirmed this is not something that Handlebars is doing, as Model-attributes are inserted as HTML-atributes into Backbone generated `div` of the `BookView` model (note, I am not providing tagName or el manually, I want Backbone to create a div for me).

So here is where I am stuck. I have a perfectly working list of HTML generated by `BookView` for each of my models in the list, but for some reason Backbone-generated div wrapper contains each of Model-attributes in its HTML-attributes, like so:

```
<div id="#library">
<div test="wtf" anotherTest="123"><b>wtf</b> 123</div>
<div test="wtf" anotherTest="123"><b>wtf</b> 123</div>
<div test="wtf" anotherTest="123"><b>wtf</b> 123</div>
</div>
```

I am really pulling my hair out over this and I have suspicion it has something to do with the fact I am trying to use View-in-a-View.

Have you encountered similar problems before? Have you got good examples of Backbone application where MasterView renders collection of ChildViews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a weird thing when creating new `BookViews`. That view is expecting a `BookModel` to come in its initialization. However, the `initialize()` method always expects an object which is called `attributes` by convention. You should modify your `BookView` so it matches this:

```
var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({

    render: function() {
       // keep the same code
    },

    initialize: function(attributes) {
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
    }
});
```

and in your `LibraryView` you should use:

```
var view = new BookView({ model : book });
```

instead of the previous:

```
var view = new BookView(film); // which is a typo, and should pass book and not film
```

So now you get your expected result.

```
<div id="library">
    <div><b>wtf</b> 123</div>
    <div><b>wtf</b> 123</div>
    <div><b>wtf</b> 123</div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that `initialize(attributes)` will automatically call set with that mapping, so you don't have to call `set(attr, value)` yourself. With that in mind, we can understand why that view is having two attributes which are in fact your two model's attributes (they are being `set()` on initialization).

Comment: yup, film was a typo. Thanks a lot! Indeed what I was missing was {model: book} and not passing the model directly into the view.